# PowerApps is creating empty rows in SharePoint

Tags: list, powerapp

I am using the following function for a PowerApps survey which is supposed to create list items in SharePoint:

```
Collect('Test List PowerApps';{Title:Radio1.Selected.Value;Column:Slider1.Value‌​;Tekst:TextInput1.Te‌​xt})
```

It does create the item, but each column is empty!

I later tried again by making an app through SharePoint. This one uses text alone:

```
Collect('Test List PowerApps';{Title:DataCardValue1.Text;Column:DataCardValue2.Text;Tekst:DataCardValue3.Text})
```

In this case, only the "Title" column gets any text. That is regardless of where I place it; So, if I switch Column and Title in function above, only the Title column gets filled with text. The different columns have the exact same settings.

Why am I experiencing this? Is there any workaround I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Try using commas instead of semicolons between each item when you are creating your row.

Comment: Well, it's too late now since I don't work there anymore. However, I do remember that while the official documentation does use commas, nothing worked unless I used semicolons (also, the in-app examples all used semicolons).